# PHP Unit doesn't detect my test - Symfony - Unit test URL Profile user Page

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

I already have several files with form or URL tests. however, for tests where user login is needed (I used Symfony's predefined loginUser function), they are not detected. when I use the command "php bin / phpunit" on the terminal, the number of tests has not increased, and these tests are not taken into account. How can I do please?
Here is the code, for example, of the test for the URL of the profile page:

```
<?php

namespace App\tests\Controller;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ProfilControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testMyProfil()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $userRepository = static::$container->get(UserRepository::class);

        //retrieve the test user (in the fixtures)
        $testUser = $userRepository->findOneByEmail('Alex@gmail.com');

        //simulate $testUser being logged in
        $client->loginUser($testUser);

        // test the profile page
        $client->request('GET', '/monProfil');
        $this -> assertEquals ( 200 , $client -> getResponse () -> getStatusCode ());
    }

}
```

Here is an example of a detected test with PHPUnit, it's also an URL test but with no login required :

```
<?php

namespace App\tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AboutControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testAbout()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        //teste the page "about us"
        $client->request('GET', '/aboutUs');
        $this -> assertEquals ( 200 , $client -> getResponse () -> getStatusCode ());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see an example of one test which is actually detect to compare ?
Also you could try with this command ```vendor\bin\phpunit``` which is the one I use

Comment: This command doesn't work on my terminal, the error is "bash: vendorbinphpunit: command not found". I added an example in my question.

Comment: The test is not running so you mean that it is NOT DETECTED by phpunit is that correct ? Can you check your ``phpunit.xsd`` file. Look at the filter>whitelist>exclude tag

Comment: yes, it is not detected by phpunit. In my phpunit.xml.dist : `<whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>`

Comment: Are you sure that in the root dir of your project, running ``vendor\bin\phpunit`` fail in error ? I'm asking because you write ``bash : vendorbinphpunit:...``

Comment: Yes, I wrote `vendor\bin\phpunit`

Comment: Is this project private or not ? Could you provide a github with a reproductible example ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the loginUser($user) function, what it does is creates a "browser token" and set it to the session. When you unit test this operation doesn't work.

What you can do is;

```php
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', []);
$client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
```

This sets the necessary token for the user and simulates the login process.

The UsernamePasswordToken class is;

```php
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken
```

For further testing, after setting the token to the client you can get the authorization_checker and check if the user is granted for a specific model.

```php
$auth = $client->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker');
$post = new Post();
$this->assertTrue($auth->isGranted(AbstractObjectsVoter::READ, $post));
```

Comment: The problem of the author is not related to how login a user in test. He just can't run this test.

Comment: Creating a token with a user and setting that token to a client does the job. After doing that client that runs the test becomes logged in.
As I said in the answer second part is for further testing.

Comment: Can you write the totality of the code please? because I tried a lot of things with your indications but have always the same problem